# Angular CLI & Material 2 Sidenav - repeating 'this._platform undefined' error

Tags: html, angular, angular-cli, angular-material2

I'm developing an app using angular material 2, which contains a `mat-sidenav` component, and whenever the `<mat-sidenav>` component is used in the template, I get the following error in the console, which repeats itself every few seconds, making debugging impossible;

[image: 'this._platform is undefined' error]

I tried to uninstall and reinstall the material package with npm, which has only resulted in producing an additional error in the CLI, as below:

[image: CLI table.js error]

It's definitely the sidenav that is causing the issue, as you can see from the console error, and specifically the `<mat-sidenav>` component within the `<mat-sidenav-container>`, because the issue isn't present with this removed.

**package.json:**

```
{
"name": "firebase-work",
"version": "0.0.0",
"license": "MIT",
"main": "main.js",
"scripts": {
  "ng": "ng",
  "start": "ng serve",
  "build": "ng build --prod",
  "test": "ng test",
  "lint": "ng lint",
  "e2e": "ng e2e",
  "deploy": "ng build --prod && firebase deploy",
  "electron": "electron .",
  "electron-build": "ng build --prod && electron ."
},
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
  "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
  "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
  "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
  "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
  "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
  "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
  "core-js": "^2.4.1",
  "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
  "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@angular/cli": "1.6.6",
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
  "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
  "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
  "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
  "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
  "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
  "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
  "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
  "karma": "~2.0.0",
  "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
  "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
  "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
  "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
  "protractor": "~5.1.2",
  "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
  "tslint": "~5.9.1",
  "typescript": "~2.5.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code of package.json?

Comment: Done...........

Comment: Missing '@angular/cdk' and '@angular/material' in dependencies?

Comment: Just tried that and it's not made any difference

Comment: Can you try deleting 'node_modules', redoing 'npm install' and 'npm start'?

Comment: You mean reinstall all packages?

Comment: Yes. That compiling error states cannot find something in '@angular/cdk'.

Comment: Would it not therefore make more sense to only reinstall cdk?

Comment: Sure. That makes it simple.